# More than 1 object in a single JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm hoping someone can push me in the right direction with this. I have 3 separate classes, `Calculator`, `Calculator2`, and a `Calculator3`. In principal they are all the same, except for a few changes to some of the buttons, so I'll just paste the code for `Calculator`. I was wondering how can I get them so all appear in a single `JFrame` next to each other in a main? I attached my most recent attempt of the main as well.

Here is `Calculator`:

```
public class Calculator implements ActionListener {
private JFrame frame;
private JTextField xfield, yfield;
private JLabel result;
private JButton subtractButton;
private JButton divideButton;
private JButton addButton;
private JButton timesButton;
private JPanel xpanel;

public Calculator() {      
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    xpanel = new JPanel();
    xpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

    xpanel.add(new JLabel("x:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    xfield = new JTextField("0", 5);
    xpanel.add(xfield);

    xpanel.add(new JLabel("y:", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    yfield = new JTextField("0", 5);
    xpanel.add(yfield);

    xpanel.add(new JLabel("Result:"));
    result = new JLabel("0");
    xpanel.add(result);
    frame.add(xpanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    /***********************************************************************
     *********************************************************************** 
     **********************************************************************/

    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();                      //New panel for the artimatic buttons
    southPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    timesButton = new JButton("Multiplication");
    southPanel.add(timesButton);
    timesButton.addActionListener(this);

    subtractButton = new JButton("Subtract");
    southPanel.add(subtractButton);
    subtractButton.addActionListener(this);

    divideButton = new JButton("Division");
    southPanel.add(divideButton);
    divideButton.addActionListener(this);

    addButton = new JButton("Addition");
    southPanel.add(addButton);
    addButton.addActionListener(this);

    frame.add(southPanel , BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    Font thisFont = result.getFont();                                       //Get current font
    result.setFont(thisFont.deriveFont(thisFont.getStyle() ^ Font.BOLD));   //Make the result bold
    result.setForeground(Color.red);                                        //Male the result answer red in color
    result.setBackground(Color.yellow);                                     //Make result background yellow
    result.setOpaque(true);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
/**
 * clear()
 * Resets the x and y field to 0 after invalid integers were input
 */
public void clear() {
    xfield.setText("0");
    yfield.setText("0");
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) { 
    String xText = xfield.getText();                        //Get the JLabel fiels and set them to strings
    String yText = yfield.getText();

    int xVal;
    int yVal;

    try {
        xVal = Integer.parseInt(xText);                     //Set global var xVal to incoming string
        yVal = Integer.parseInt(yText);                     //Set global var yVal to incoming string
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {                       //xVal or yVal werent valid integers, print message and don't continue
        result.setText("ERROR");
        clear();
        return ;
    } 

    if(event.getSource().equals(timesButton)) {             //Button pressed was multiply
        result.setText(Integer.toString(xVal*yVal)); 
    }
    else if(event.getSource().equals(divideButton)) {       //Button pressed was division
        if(yVal == 0) {                                   //Is the yVal (bottom number) 0?
            result.setForeground(Color.red);              //Yes it is, print message
            result.setText("CAN'T DIVIDE BY ZERO!");
            clear();
        }
        else          
            result.setText(Integer.toString(xVal/yVal));  //No it's not, do the math
    }
    else if(event.getSource().equals(subtractButton)) {    //Button pressed was subtraction                                          
        result.setText(Integer.toString(xVal-yVal)); 
    }
    else if(event.getSource().equals(addButton)) {        //Button pressed was addition
        result.setText(Integer.toString(xVal+yVal)); 
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my current main:

```
public class DemoCalculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Calculators");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    Calculator2 calc2 = new Calculator2();
    JPanel calcPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel calcPanel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    //calcPanel.add(calc, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //calcPanel2.add(calc2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(calcPanel);
    mainPanel.add(calcPanel2);
    calcPanel.add(mainPanel);

    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(calcPanel);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(calcPanel2);
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a single JFrame and put your Calculator classes each into a single JPanel.Don't create a new JFrame for each class.

```
public class Calculator{ 

JPanel panel;
public Calculator(){

  panel = new JPanel();

  /*
  *  Add labels and buttons etc.
  */
   panel.add(buttons);
   panel.add(labels);
}

  //Method to return the JPanel
  public JPanel getPanel(){
  return panel;
 }
}
```

Then add the panels to your JFrame in your testers class using whatever layout best suits your needs.

```
public class DemoCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPanel cal1,cal2;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculators");

    frame.add(cal1 = new Calculator().getPanel(),new BorderLayout().EAST);
    frame.add(cal2 = new Calculator2().getPanel(),new BorderLayout().WEST);

    frame.setSize(1000,600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  } 
}
```